# jquery checkbox - check for values in the array and check those values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array say

```
{'Sunday','Wednesday', 'Thursday'}
```

I have a checkboxes with all week days.

```
HTML code
<tr>
    <td width="3%"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="weeklyDay"
           id="sunday" value="sunday"> Sunday
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="weeklyDay"
           checked id="monday" value="monday"> Monday
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="weeklyDay"
           id="tuesday" value="tuesday"> Tuesday
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="weeklyDay"
           id="wednesday" value="wednesday"> Wednesday
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="3%"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked
           name="thursday" id="thursday" value="thursday"> Thursday
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="weeklyDay"
           id="friday" value="friday"> Friday
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="weeklyDay"
           id="saturday" value="saturday"> Saturday
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to find out only sunday, wednesday and thursday and check these three. How to do it? 
could someone help me to check multiple boxes based on array value change ? 
Thanks

Comment: Let's see the HTML for those checkboxes. When do you want to set them as `checked`?

Comment: I will receive data from server and based on that i have to select checkboxes. I have edited the post adding html.

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter to [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) elements and use [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) on array of week days to match the option will in week array,

```
var weekArray =  {'Sunday','Wednesday', 'Thursday'};
$('select[name="Day"] option').filter(function(){
    if(weekArray.indexOf((this).text(), 0) != -1)
       return $(this);
}).prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: There's no `:option` selector in jQuery, there should be a space between `select[name="Day"]` and `option`, and you should be using `.prop()` not `.attr()` to set them as selected (not checked). That's all kind of irrelevant, however, since the question says checkboxes (though may have been edited after you posted your answer).

Comment: var ds = $("#Day").val().split(/ +/); // ds has got sunday, wednesday, thursday values now. 
var weekArray = [];
   alert("ds length" + ds.length);
   for (var i=0; i<ds.length; i++){
 weekArray = ds[i];
  $('select[name="weeklyDay"] option').filter(function(){
      if(weekArray.indexOf((this).text(), 0) != -1);
      return $(this);
 }).prop("checked", true);
}

This is what I have done. But I am not getting any values checked in checkbox. Am I making any mistake?